# Golang x509: Certificate is valid for *.<DNS> not <DB_hostname>

Tags: go, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to connect to MySQL DB using SSL via Golang and I am getting this error message

> x509: certificate is valid for *., not <DB_hostname>

I have created certificates using this tutorial
https://www.devdungeon.com/content/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-openssl

Function to create TLSConf:

```golang
func createTLSConf() tls.Config {

    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("certificate.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
    }
    clientCert := make([]tls.Certificate, 0, 1)

    certs, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("certificate.pem", "privkey.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    clientCert = append(clientCert, certs)

    return tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            rootCertPool,
        Certificates:       clientCert,
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
    }
}
```

Connection to DB

```golang
    tlsConf := createTLSConf()  
    err := mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tlsConf)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error %s when RegisterTLSConfig\n", err)
        return
    }

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s?tls=custom", "user", "pass", "db_host", "db_name")
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error %s when opening DB\n", err)
        log.Printf("%s", dsn)
        return
    }
```

Using connection

```golang
    defer db.Close()

    e := db.Ping()
    fmt.Println(dsn, e)

    db.Close()
```

Output:

```
<user>:<pass>@tcp(<db_host>)/<db_name>?tls=custom x509: certificate is valid for *.abc-xy-pxc, not <db_host>
```

abc-xy is a part of db_host and also abc_xy is the db_name, nut sure if it is important

When changing InsecureSkipVerify to true, the output looks like this:

```
[mysql] 2022/10/21 22:31:27 packets.go:37: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority
```

Any idea how can I get this to work?

EDIT:

Sooo, I don't know why, but removing part of the code with Client certificates and changing InsecureSkipVerify to true solved the issue:

```
func createTLSConf() tls.Config {

    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("certificate.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
        log.Fatal("Failed to append PEM.")
    }

    return tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            rootCertPool,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true, // needed for self signed certs
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your MySQL client library doesn't allow/support wildcard certificates. How was the certificate generated originally?

Comment: I'm pretty new to SSL certificates, so I'm not sure if this is answer to your question, but it went like that
1. openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048
2. openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out signreq.csr
3. openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in signreq.csr -signkey privkey.pem -out certificate.pem

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am also new to Go but you can give this a try. Consider my answer might not be the best but I am trying to be more active by helping and asking. You can generate your certificates in terminal and then use them.

run this in terminal at your project directory. (where your main.go located) and the /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go should be the directory where Go standard library is installed.

`go run /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go --rsa-bits=2048 --host=localhost`

open a DB connection return errors if any:

```
func openDB(dsn string) (*sql.DB, error){
   db, err := sql.Open("mysql",dsn)
   if err!= nil{
      return nil,err
   }
   if err = db.Ping();err!=nil{
      return nil,err
   }
   return db,nil
}
```

Then you have to configure your server settings. You will have a http.Server with your pem files.

declare a variable of crypto/tls.Config where only elliptic curves with assembly implementation are used.

```
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
   CurvePreferences:[]tls.CurveID{tls.X25519,tls.CurveP256}
}
```

then declare your server.

```
yourServer := &http.Server{
   //Your configs
   TLSConfig : tlsConfig,
   //Your other configs if any
}
```

Now we have created our server with specific TLS configuration. All you have to do is running your server now. However, you have to update your server's method with ListenAndServeTLS(first arg = cert,second arg = key)

```
err = srv.ListenAndServeTLS(<Location of your cert.pem>, <Location of your key.pem>)
```

Comment: I have created something using your tips, I'm not sure if I did everything right, but I get this error message:

listen tcp x.y.z.a:443: bind: cannot assign requested address

Comment: I edit original post, I forgot `return db,nil`  line in openDB() func.

Regarding your question, check your host address and port configurations.

Comment: I fixed the part you mentioned and then got the error message. As I said in edit, I got it to work somehow. As for your suggestion, I don't really get the ports, for me it works without specifying one, so I guess it uses default port and as for the host I'm sure I was using the correct name. Anyway, thanks for your support!